# How to reduce the length of a column selection in Pycharm/Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm

As can be seen in the screenshot the blue area represents a column-mode selection that is one line too long.

[image]

While the `shift-up/down-arrow` key increases the length of the selection, I can not discover any key combination to  *reduce* its length. Instead I just start over each time. Is such a capability available?

Comment: Start the selection from one line and extend/reduce it using shift+up/down arrows to the other lines. For example, if you start it from `- name...` line, shift+down arrow will extend it down, while shift+up will either reduce the selection or extend it up. If it's not what you observe, please try to share a video of the problem.

Comment: @CrazyCoder   The behavior is the `shift-up` will extend it up - I don't see / am not sure how to use it to reduce the selection

Comment: If you started the selection from the line with `name` and extended it down with shift+down, shift+up will reduce it up to the start line, but will extend it further up if you continue to press this key. This behavior is by design and is the least surprising.

Comment: `shift-up` only adds to the length no matter what I do. This has been the case for as long as I have used JetBrains products (2008) .  You're apparently saying that some way of using `shift-up` does not do it but I've never seen it.  Just now I tried a single stroke of `shift-up` then remove `shift`. The behavior is the whole selection immediately expands even on the first stroke. Apparently I need detailed instructions on key sequences to make this work - is there a video?

Comment: Here is the video: https://i.imgur.com/OvwcQVc.gif.

Comment: Thanks @CrazyCoder!  Watched the video but it just tells me that you're seeing different results.   I presume you're using shift-up to diminish the length?  I don't see that behavior: shift-up always extends does not diminish.

Comment: I'm using Shift+Up to select Up and Shift+Down to select Down. The selection will always expand from the line where you start it and will reduce to the same line, then will expand in the other direction. If both Up and Down actions behave the same for you, check the keymap settings: https://i.imgur.com/Axtlqek.png.

Comment: I checked settings and removed `Shift-up` from `Extend selection to cell above [python]`  But that did not change the behavior.

Comment: Try with the new IntelliJ IDEA installation and/or with the default settings: File | Manage IDE Settings | Restore Default Settings...: https://i.imgur.com/kbrkC7w.png.

Comment: @CrazyCoder  Ok will do that.  If you want to put an answer along the lines of "Try out the default keymap" i can award.  *Thank you for taking the time to help here*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I failed to reproduce the described behavior with the default keymap:

[image: selection]

It may help to reset the keymap bindings to the defaults or to reset all the IDE settings: File | Manage IDE Settings | Restore Default Settings.

Comment: This is a solid approach: reset the keymap.  I will report back after trying this out.